# Regex password issue

Tags: regex

Working on a project where it requires me to have a password field using pattern attribute.
Not really done a lot of regex stuff and was wondering whether someone could help out.

The requirements for the field are as follows:

- Can't contain the word "password"
- Must be 8-12 in length
- Must have 1 upper case
- Must have 1 lower case
- Must have 1 digit

Now, so far I have the following:

```
[^(password)].(?=.*[0-9])?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}
```

This doesn't work. We can get it so everything else works, apart from the password string being matched.

Thanks in advance,
Andy

**EDIT:** the method we've used now (nested in comments below) is:
    `^(?!.*(P|p)(A|a)(S|s)(S|s)(W|w)(O|o)(R|r)(D|d)).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$`

Thanks for the help

Comment: I tried all the ones that I could find on stackoverflow and couldn't find one that worked correct for html5

Comment: Why do your requirements list a maximum of 12 characters? This isn't the 1960s anymore, most hardware/software today can handle  longer passwords. http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=936:_Password_Strength

Comment: It's just in the spec for what the company requested, not my business to advice and things like that unfortuneately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should to the job:

```
^(?!.*password)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,12}$
```

it will match:

```
^               // from the beginning of the input 
(?!.*password)  // negative lookbehind whether the text contains password
(?=.*\d+)       // positive lookahead for at least one digit
(?=.*[A-Z]+)    // positive lookahead for at least one uppercase letter
(?=.*[a-z]+)    // positive lookahead for at least one lowercase letter
.{8,12}         // length of the input is between 8 and 12 characters
$
```

Link to [phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1Gv)

Comment: This is similar to what I used, and this seemed to work great. Thanks!

Comment: This will match even if it contains PassWoRd, try using this at the front instead ^(?!.*((?i)password)) will match any cased 'password'

Comment: Look at my answer for simple solution !

Comment: We were just talking about this now, that you can use a different case for it. Will try this now. Thanks

Comment: We've come up with this solution `^(?!.*(P|p)(A|a)(S|s)(S|s)(W|w)(O|o)(R|r)(D|d)).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}$`

Comment: Small edit, `^(?!.*(P|p)(A|a)(S|s)(S|s)(W|w)(O|o)(R|r)(D|d)).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$` as the previous wasn't allowed capital at the start

Comment: @Srb1313711 , Your doubt will clear my answer ! The PassWoRd was change ToUpper() characters and i checked the validation

Comment: why the plus signs after the character classes? it will work just as well without them

Comment: Oh okay, thanks, never really touched regex much, usually implement validation in other forms.

Answer (score 2):

Use a series of anchored look aheads for the :must contain" criteria:

```
^(?!.*(?i)password)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}$
```

I've added the "ignore case" switch `(?i)` to the "password" requirement, so it will reject `the word no matter the case of the letters.

Comment: +1 just don't forget the `$` at the end

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to get it to work for any case in html5

Comment: we've come up with this solution `^(?!.*(P|p)(A|a)(S|s)(S|s)(W|w)(O|o)(R|r)(D|d)).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}$`

Comment: Small edit, `^(?!.*(P|p)(A|a)(S|s)(S|s)(W|w)(O|o)(R|r)(D|d)).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$` as the previous wasn't allowed capital at the start

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
^(?!.*password)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,12}$
```

Explanation

```
^                         Start anchor
(?=.*[A-Z])               Ensure string has one uppercase letter
(?=.*[0-9])               Ensure string has one digits.
(?=.*[a-z])               Ensure string has one lowercase letter
{8,12}                    Ensure string is of length 8 - 12.
(?!.*password)            Not of word password
$                         End anchor.
```

Comment: your password check expression is pretty messed up: right now it means "must contain a character other than one of `()adoprsw`"

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
        Public void validation()
        string xxxx = "Aa1qqqqqq";
        if (xxxx.ToUpper().Contains("password") || !(xxxx.Length <= 12 & xxxx.Length >= 8) || !IsMatch(xxxx, "(?=.*[A-Z])") || !IsMatch(xxxx, "(?=.*[a-z])") || !IsMatch(xxxx, "(?=.*[0-9])"))
        {
             throw new System.ArgumentException("Your error message here", "Password");
        }
        }

        public bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern)
        {
          Match xx = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
          return xx.Success;
         }
```

Comment: We're using regex in html5

Comment: Same as I also used Regex , See that IsMatch method , My code helps for check your all requirement for password , if all is correct the if condition is return false, other wise that if  condition will true, then add the error message there !You can check it !